# Could someone please check my proof that $(x_n) \text{ is Cauchy in } X\implies (f(x_n)) \text{ is Cauchy in } Y$

Tags: proof-verification, metric-spaces, proof-writing, alternative-proof, cauchy-sequences

Let $(X,d)$ and $(Y,\rho)$ be metric spaces and $f:X\to Y$.

Show that if $f:X\to Y$ is uniformly continuous, then

$$(x_n) \text{ is Cauchy in } X\implies (f(x_n)) \text{ is Cauchy in } Y$$

My working:

Since $f$ is uniformly continuous then $\forall\epsilon>0, \exists\delta>0$ s.t.  $\forall x,x'\in X, d(x,x')<\delta\implies\rho(f(x),f(x'))<\epsilon$

But since $(x_n)$ is Cauchy in $X$, then $\forall\epsilon>0, \exists N$ s.t. $\forall m,n\geq N\implies d(x_m,x_n)<\epsilon$.

Then $\forall\epsilon>0,\exists\delta>0$ s.t. $\exists N$ s.t. $\forall m,n\geq N\implies d(x_m,x_n)<\delta\implies\rho(f(x_m),f(x_n))<\epsilon$.

So we have shown that $\forall\epsilon>0, \exists N$ s.t. $\forall m,n\geq N\implies \rho(f(x_m),f(x_n))<\epsilon$.

Hence $(f(x_n)) \text{ is Cauchy in } Y$.

Could anybody please check my working whether it is correct? If so, how can I write in a better way? If it is wrong, where did I make the mistake?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think there is a typo in "Then $∀ϵ>0,∃δ>0$  s.t. $∃N$ s.t. $∀m,n≥N⟹d(x_m,x_n)<δ⟹ρ(f(x),f(x′))<ϵ$". I think it would be "...$ρ(f(x_m),f(x_n))<ϵ$".

Comment: @user170039 Yes you're right. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't intend to write a completely new proof because your argument looks fine to me but I think that you can write the proof in a more systematic way. Although I think that your essential idea is correct, it is better to emphasize a few subtleties in the writing of the proof.

> Since $f$ is uniformly continuous then $$∀ϵ>0,∃δ>0\mid ∀x,x′∈X,d(x,x′)<δ⟹ρ(f(x),f(x′))<ϵ\tag{1}$$ But since $(x_n)$ is Cauchy in $X$, then $$∀ϵ>0,∃N\mid ∀m,n≥N⟹d(x_m,x_n)<\epsilon\tag{2}$$
>
> **Now let us choose $\epsilon>0$. Then by $(1)$ $\color{red}{\text{for our particular choice of}}$ $\epsilon>0$ we can write,** $$∃δ>0\mid ∀x,x′∈X,d(x,x′)<δ⟹ρ(f(x),f(x′))<ϵ\tag{3}$$ **Now let us choose any $\delta>0$ which satisfies $(3)$. Then for $\color{red}{\text{that}}$ $\delta>0$ we will have by $(2)$,** $$∃N\mid ∀m,n≥N⟹d(x_m,x_n)<\delta\tag{4}$$**Now by $(1)$ $\color{red}{\text{for our particular choice(s) of}}$ $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ we have,** $$\exists N\mid (\forall m,n\ge N)\land(\forall x_m,x_n\in X), d(x_m,x_n)<\delta\implies \rho(f(x_m),f(x_n))<\varepsilon$$ **Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary so we can write,** $$∀ϵ>0,(∃δ>0)\land(∃N) \mid ∀m,n≥N⟹d(x_m,x_n)<δ⟹ρ(f(x_m),f(x_n))<ϵ$$
> So we have shown that $$∀ϵ>0,∃N\mid ∀m,n≥N⟹ρ(f(x_m),f(x_n))<ϵ$$
> Hence $(f(x_n))$ is Cauchy in $Y$.

Answer (score 1):

the result is correct but in the demonstration it is best not to
confuse the symbol $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$

Since $f$ is uniformly continuous then
$\forall\epsilon>0, \exists\delta>0$ s.t.  $\forall x,x'\in X,
d(x,x')<\delta\Rightarrow\rho(f(x),f(x'))<\epsilon$

But since $(x_n)$ is Cauchy in $X$, then $\forall\delta>0, \exists
N$ s.t. $\forall m,n\geq N\Rightarrow d(x_m,x_n)<\delta$.

Then $\forall\epsilon>0,\exists\delta>0$ s.t. $\exists N$ s.t.
$\forall m,n\geq N\Rightarrow
d(x_m,x_n)<\delta\Rightarrow\rho(f(x_m),f(x_n))<\epsilon$.

So we have shown that $\forall\epsilon>0, \exists N$ s.t. $\forall
m,n\geq N\Rightarrow \rho(f(x_m),f(x_n))<\epsilon$.